# Hortonworks Sanbox Error: Connection failed to http://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:50070

Tags: hadoop, virtualbox, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-sandbox

I am receiving the following error on the Hortonworks HDP Sandbox:

Connection failed to http://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:50070 (<urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>)

[image]

All of the solutions I found online, were to give it time, to start all and to restart. I have waited for over a day now and it does not work still. I have clocked the start all and no changes.
For "restart all" it seems to be grayed out from the image below:

[image]

Any reason for why this is grayed out?

Please let me know if there is any action I can do to have this working. I have 29 Alerts from the Sandbox it is all due to this error. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Here is the full strack trace:

java.net.ConnectException: sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:50070: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:242)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner.connect(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:722)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner.connect(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:674)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner.runWithRetry(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:747)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner.access$100(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:592)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner$1.run(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:622)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner.run(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:618)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.getHdfsFileStatus(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:1004)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.getFileStatus(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:1020)
at org.apache.ambari.view.utils.hdfs.HdfsApi$4.run(HdfsApi.java:216)
at org.apache.ambari.view.utils.hdfs.HdfsApi$4.run(HdfsApi.java:214)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
at org.apache.ambari.view.utils.hdfs.HdfsApi.execute(HdfsApi.java:513)
at org.apache.ambari.view.utils.hdfs.HdfsApi.execute(HdfsApi.java:489)
at org.apache.ambari.view.utils.hdfs.HdfsApi.getFileStatus(HdfsApi.java:214)
at org.apache.ambari.view.commons.hdfs.UserService.homeDir(UserService.java:67)
at org.apache.ambari.view.hive20.resources.files.FileService.userhomeSmokeTest(FileService.java:256)
at org.apache.ambari.view.hive20.HelpService.userhomeStatus(HelpService.java:89)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:137)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:137)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:137)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:137)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1507)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.apache.ambari.server.security.authorization.AmbariAuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AmbariAuthorizationFilter.java:287)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.apache.ambari.server.security.authentication.AmbariDelegatingAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AmbariDelegatingAuthenticationFilter.java:132)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.apache.ambari.server.security.authorization.AmbariUserAuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AmbariUserAuthorizationFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
at org.apache.ambari.server.api.MethodOverrideFilter.doFilter(MethodOverrideFilter.java:72)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
at org.apache.ambari.server.api.AmbariPersistFilter.doFilter(AmbariPersistFilter.java:47)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
at org.apache.ambari.server.view.AmbariViewsMDCLoggingFilter.doFilter(AmbariViewsMDCLoggingFilter.java:54)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
at org.apache.ambari.server.view.ViewThrottleFilter.doFilter(ViewThrottleFilter.java:161)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
at org.apache.ambari.server.security.AbstractSecurityHeaderFilter.doFilter(AbstractSecurityHeaderFilter.java:125)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
at org.apache.ambari.server.security.AbstractSecurityHeaderFilter.doFilter(AbstractSecurityHeaderFilter.java:125)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:294)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:427)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariHandlerList.processHandlers(AmbariHandlerList.java:212)
at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariHandlerList.processHandlers(AmbariHandlerList.java:201)
at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariHandlerList.handle(AmbariHandlerList.java:150)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:973)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1035)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:641)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)